# Looking for a way to pass Image<Bgr, byte> from bitmap using EmguCV

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, emgucv, face-recognition

Currently, I'm looking for a solution to my problem which is the fact that I need 
to pass the `Image<Bgr, byte>` object to one of recognizer method while so far I operate with `Bitmap` object (which by the way is a rectangle cropped from original `Bitmap`).

So the question is how can I recreate an `Image<Bgr, byte>` from `Bitmap`.
For now I use the solution that passes two arguments but I consider it redundant. I belive OpenCV or maybe EmguCV itself should provide some conversion solution but I wasn't able to track it so far.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you need to create an `Image<Bgr, byte>` from a `Bitmap`, the `Image` class has a [constructor](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/3.3.0/document/html/791fbe59-17c0-26e7-efa7-a1d1ad146ac4.htm) just for that.